# Use V2Ray with an http proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, tunnel

I would like to use SSH and others with the school network. However, the school network output is totally blocked. The only way to get to the Internet is by using a Squid HTTP proxy, it supports CONNECT method for HTTPS. I started to plan using a shadowsocks proxy tunneled via V2Ray and WebSocket. It works at home but i can't find a way to instruct V2Ray to use the http squid proxy.

I tried to do a transparent proxy, but it doesn't work with a local Squid HTTP proxy.

```
# Client config
{
    "server":"138.201.145.226",
    "server_port":80,
    "local_port":2554,
    "password":"_redacted_",
    "timeout":600,
    "method":"chacha20-ietf-poly1305",
    "plugin": "v2ray-plugin",
    "plugin_opts": "loglevel=debug;host=redacted.host"
}

# WPAD for the school network
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "127.0.0.0", "255.255.255.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "10.129.0.0", "255.255.0.0") ||
        isInNet(myIpAddress(), "10.167.191.0", "255.255.255.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "192.168.228.0", "255.255.255.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "10.167.191.0", "255.255.255.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "10.167.224.0", "255.255.224.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "10.167.191.0", "255.255.255.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "10.167.224.0", "255.255.224.0")
    )
    {
        return "DIRECT";
    };
    return "PROXY 192.168.228.254:3128";
}
```